# Different ways of choosing two subsets from a set

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

***S* is a set containing 10 elements. A subset *P* of *S* is chosen at random and the set *S* is reconstructed. Now another subset *Q* of *S* is chosen at random. Find the probabilities that-**

$1)$ $P \cap Q$ contain exactly $3$ elements;
$2)$ $P \cup Q$ contain exactly $4$ elements;
$3)$ $P \cup Q = S$

Please try to give a good explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Say something about what you think about this.

Comment: What do you mean by "the set S is reconstructed"???

Comment: It means the elements of P are replaced.

Comment: @barakmanos Here the word "reconstruted" is used just to make sure that choosing elements for P does not affect the choosing process for Q

Comment: There is no _probability_ associated with the question. What does choosing a subset of $S$ as random mean? Is each of the $2^{10}$ different subsets equally likely to be chosen? Or do the elements of $S$ have probabilities $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{10}$ and the probability of a choosing a subset $Q$ is just the probability of the event $Q$?

Comment: @Dilip: Uniform distribution is the standard assumption in questions of this type.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes of course, but I am not sure that the OP understands what exactly has the uniform distribution in this problem, or that there are two independent samples from a uniform distribution on $\{0, 1, \ldots, 1023\}$ being considered here.

Comment: All the 10 elements are equally likely to be chosen i.e. Uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ll get you started. $S$ has $10$ elements, so it has $2^{10}=1024$ subsets. Thus, there are $2^{10}\cdot 2^{10}=2^{20}$ possible ordered pairs $\langle P,Q\rangle$ of subsets that you could pick, and they are all equally likely. To find the probability that $|P\cap Q|=3$, therefore, we need to count the ordered pairs $\langle P,Q\rangle$ such that $|P\cap Q|=3$ and divide that number by $2^{20}$.

One way to do this is to count the pairs that have each possible $3$-element intersection. Let $T$ be a $3$-element subset of $S$; we want to count the ordered pairs $\langle P,Q\rangle$ of subsets of $S$ such that $P\cap Q=T$. The trick here is to realize that each one of these pairs comes from a division of $S\setminus T$ into $3$ pairwise disjoint sets: for each element $k$ of $S\setminus T$ we must decide whether $k$ is to be in $P$, in $Q$, or in neither $P$ nor $Q$. $S\setminus T$ has $7$ elements, so we’re making a $3$-way choice $7$ times; this can be done in $3^7$ different ways. Thus, there are $3^7$ pairs $\langle P,Q\rangle$ such that $P\cap Q=T$. And there are $\binom{10}3$ possible choices for $T$, so there must altogether be $\binom{10}33^7$ ordered pairs $\langle P,Q\rangle$ of subsets of $S$ such that $|P\cap Q|=3$. The probability of getting such a pair is therefore

$$\frac{\binom{10}33^7}{2^{20}}=\frac{262,440}{1,048,576}=\frac{32805}{131072}\approx0.2503\;.$$

The other two parts can be analyzed using basically the same ideas. You’ll be dividing up either $P\cup Q$ or $S$ into $3$ parts.

Comment: Thank you....now I get it....

Comment: @Sujan: You’re welcome; glad it helped.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Does answer to second question $\dfrac{{10 \choose 4}3^{4}}{4^{20}}$ correct?

Comment: @mathophile: Almost: the numerator is right, but the denominator should be $2^{10}\cdot 2^{10}=2^{20}$, the number of ordered pairs of subsets of $S$, just as in the first question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks.

Comment: @mathophile: You’re welcome.